# How to adjust margins in Kaobook?

Tags: layout, kaobook

Wondering how I can set page margins on Kaobook? I have these requirements from the Uni:
4cm binding margin
2cm head margin
2.5cm fore-edge margin
4cm tail margin
Page size A4 (I have seen the question on page size, so maybe ignore this one!)

Thanks

Comment: The page layout is defined here: https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook/blob/master/styles/kao.sty but I wouldn't change it, since the values are carefully chosen and changing them will most probably break things

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related.

Comment: Thanks @yo' that's great.

Comment: @DG' thanks. ya I know the sty file, was wondering if the author would be able to give a better solution instead of changing the default values.

Comment: I agree with @DG'. Changing the default values is not necessarily a bad thing, but if you don't want to edit the `kao.sty` file, then you can redefine the \marginlayout command in the preamble of your main.tex (updating the varius lengths) or use \geometry as suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Kaobook's documentation explains how to change the page's margins at section 6.5 "Page Layout" (page 30 at the moment).

Put this code before the beginning of the document and change the values as you will.

```
\renewcommand{\marginlayout}{%
    \newgeometry{
        top=27.4mm,             % height of the top margin
        bottom=27.4mm,          % height of the bottom margin
        inner=24.8mm,           % width of the inner margin
        textwidth=117mm,        % width of the text
        marginparsep=8.2mm,     % width between text and margin
        marginparwidth=39.4mm,  % width of the margin
    }%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [geometry](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) like that:

```
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=4cm,
    inner=2.5cm,
    textwidth=\hpll*\real{107},
    marginparsep=\hpll*\real{8.2},
    marginparwidth=\hpll*\real{49.4},
    includemp,
    showframe   % <--- This option helps to see the layout. Remove in the end.
}
```

[image]

But it will almost certainly break things!